# How to have multiple passport for different user types in MEAN stack

Tags: mean-stack

In my project, I am using the passport feature in MEAN stack for user authentication. I have logins for 4 different user types(patient , doctor , and so on.) Can I have multiple passports for all different user types??
Below mentioned is the code for User(patient) Passport. I tried creating different passports, but I don't know how to link them to the project.

```
const passport = require('passport');
const localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var User = mongoose.model('User');
passport.use(
new localStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' },
    (username, password, done) => {
        User.findOne({ email: username },
            (err, user) => {
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                // unknown user
                else if (!user)
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Email is not registered' });
                // wrong password
                else if (!user.verifyPassword(password))
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Wrong password.' });
                // authentication succeeded
                else
                    return done(null, user);
            });
    })
);
```